# Exponentiation in a low complexity way

Tags: algorithm, integer-arithmetic

I want to compute q^k, s.t. q is n bits wide, in the limitations:

1. the final result will be n*k bits wide.
2. for every step of the calculation, the result of multiplying x,y s.t. x is |x| bits wide and y is |y| bits wide is |x|*|y| bits wide.

I tried to do that in pairs; start with the q^2's, then q^4's, etc.
The 1st step result takes 2n bits, the 2nd takes (2^2)n bits, etc. and the last step takes n*2^(logk) (=kn) bits.
We have log(k) steps, and a Careful calculation brings us to: 
O(log(n)(log(k))^2).
I'd be happy to hear about a faster way of doing that (or a better analysis of this algorithm or a similar), in the above restrictions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=exponentiation+by+squaring

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#Alternatives_and_generalizations

Comment: @SargeBorsch it's better to link to a specific result instead rather than Google

Comment: thanks, but I think you're disregarding the limitations above; multplying takes log(n) only if O(n) is the wide of the result, and here we have the extra variable k, which leads to an O(n*k) bits wide result, and a growing bits-wide result in each step.
Or I just didn't understand this algorithm?

Comment: "multiplying x,y s.t. x is |x| bits wide and y is |y| bits wide is |x|*|y| bits wide" It's |x| + |y|.

Comment: it's a typo; my previous comment and post meaning remain the same.
q*q-> 2|q| bits wide.
(q*(q*q))^2 = q^2*q^4 = q^6 -> 6|q| bits wide.
...q^k -> k*|q| bits wide.
we still have this extra variable, how do you get rid of it?

Comment: Unless you show us some code, it's hard to know what your "Careful calculation" refers to and how you derived it.  Also, what's this "extra variable" you're referring to? @DavidEisenstat is right, your claim 2 is faulty, and that further muddies the waters. I don't feel you've described your problem clearly and in sufficient detail for us to respond meaningfully.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that multiplications with `n`-bit outputs have cost `n f(n)` for some function `f` that is positive and nondecreasing, the final multiplication costs asymptotically no less than the rest of the work. Preparing the squares for `q^k` where `q` has `n` bits costs

```
   2 n f(2 n) + 4 n f(4 n) + ... + 2^floor(lg(k)) f(2^floor(lg(k)) n)
<= (2 n + 4 n + ... + 2^floor(lg(k)) n) f(2^floor(lg(k)) n)
<= 2 (2^floor(lg(k)) n) f(2^floor(lg(k)) n)
<= 2 k n f(k n),
```

which is twice the cost of the final multiplication. The other multiplications can be analyzed similarly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best integer pow is **O(2*Log2(K))** when going through bits of k.

- k can be written in binary form k = { kn-1,...k3,k2,k1,k0 }

so equation looks like this:

```
q^k = q^( 1*k0 +2*k1 +4*k2 +8*k3 ... )
q^k = q^k0 * q^(2*k1) * q^(4*k2) ....
```

- so you have only n = ceil(log2(k)) steps to compute
- each step multiply q^i to result if ki!=0
- q(i+1)=qi*qi
- q0 = q

simplified working code (does not handle special cases 0^k,k^0,0^0,...):

```
DWORD pow(DWORD q,DWORD k)
    {
    DWORD s;
    for (s=1;k;k>>=1,q*=q)
     if (k&1) s*=q; 
    return s;
    }
```

of course if you want to use big q,k than bigint arithmetics is needed instead

- i do not think that pairing low bits multiplications will be of much help
- unless used for really big numbers
- because the pairing and merging different bit-count sub-results is usually slower